# Generating a filter loop based off of two criteria in another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

At my job I have automated a very manual task and to the point they have wanted to expand it to the other department where they work a little differently. So the goal of this is I want to be able to filter column "A" and then filter another column based off of phrases that I already have in place as well. The data in column "A" I would have a source in another sheet, but it would have around potentially 200-400 possibilities to look for. After it filters column A I then want it go to column "AG" and then do another loop filtering based off of provided key phrases that the analyst would select based on a data validation. Once it filters those two criteria I then have the codes in place to generate the spreadsheets for the analyst. The code below is an example of the first block, I have 4 other codes that are pretty much the same they just generate different templates, I had to do multiple codes cause I didn't know how to do a loop based off of a source.

```
Sub Generate_Consolidated_Update_Reports()



Dim EDI As String

EDI = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\desktop\foldername\foldername2\foldername3\filename " & 
Format(Now(), "MM.DD.YY")


Workbooks("Master(where the filtering happens)").Activate

'The next line of code I am just doing the second filtering which is based off of a data validation 
'I created, essentially the analyst would just select a key phrase and then that would 
'prompt the code to generate the template, I haven't figured out how to do it based off of
'the source that's why I just have the specific name in the key range

'The first step to the code would need to be looking for anything in column "A", but like 
'I said that could be anywhere from 200-400 possibilities. I have access to it, though and have 
'it listed in "Sheet2" along with the phrases in column "AG" as well. 

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AG:AG" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Selection
    .autofilter Field:=33, Criteria1:="Send to EDI Team - Account Level"
    .Offset(1, 0).Select
End With

'The next line of code will be seeing if it is empty, I realized that it would work once,
'but if there ever was data the next line of looking for empty would always
'just filter anyways and keep creating the template even though there was no data
'so I did this route where if it saw it was empty I called another code, would be awesome
'if I could figure that out too!
'This then goes on repeat down the line, it's 5 different codes, so it isn't clean. :/
'so I only did one so you wouldn't see a ton of fluff!
Dim Lr As Long

Lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If Lr > 1 Then
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs EDI & ".XLS"
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "EDI Account Update"

       'Redacted code, just fluff on creating the template for the analyst
       'Next line is just doing the code to show all the data again
       'Then within that if statement to then call another sub that is essentially the same process
       'If the code doesn't find it it goes to else where it then just calls the other sub
        

        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Range("A1").Select
        Call Create_EDI_Update_GroupLevel
Else
        
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Range("A1").Select
        Call Create_EDI_Update_GroupLevel
        
End If

    
    
End Sub
```

The reason I have to also call other subs is because each criteria they select will generate a completely different template based on company policies and such.
Really sorry if this isn't clear, I am still learning coding and just having a hard time trying to explain exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment but not enough reputation yet.

One question I have is: Are you filtering on one phrase among 200-400 or can it be multiple?

I can't be sure, however an Advanced Filter might help you in this case. It is not possible for me to go into all the details. There is a very good tutorial on Youtube about this (where I learned myself): [VBA Advanced Filter - The FASTEST way to Copy and Filter Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YNhxVu2a5s)

You can also use "Worksheet_Change" event to fill in the filter. Couple it with:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target,rngRange) is Nothing Then
     ' Your code here
     ' Where rngRange is a Range object that you want the change event to catch
     
End If
```

Another note is, you can use (considering data starts at "A1") `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` if you don't have any completely empty rows within your data instead of `.End(xlUp)`. Actually you can use CurrentRegion in any cell that is inside the data range. Check out the behaviour by pressing `CTRL + *` after selecting a cell.

```
Dim rngData as Range

Set rngData = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

' ws can be a worksheet object you can set alike range above or worksheet codename
' or Worksheet("SheetName")
' Then rngData.Row will give the top row of rngData
' rngData.Column will give you you the leftmost column
' rngData.Rows.Count will give the number of rows
' rngData.Columns.Count will give the number of columns
' rngData.resize() and rngData.Offset() helps a lot too, can be used in same line
' i.e., rngData.offset(2,0).resize(1,1) : move the range 2 rows down, resize to 1 row,1 column

' Do whatever with rngData
' After you are done clean up, doesn't matter most of the time in VBA but this is better
' from what I have read/learned from others
 Set rngData = Nothing
```

This may not be the exact answer you are looking for, but may get you started. The video is 20 minutes long, see if it can be used in your case.

**Edit 1: To further clarify**

rngData part is more a general approach. You haven't said anything about being able to use Advanced Filtering but here how I would do it.

Assume, we have 3 sheets. wsData, wsFilter, wsReport.
wsData would be the sheet where data is entered.
wsFilter would only hold the filter criteria.
wsReport would be the sheet that you will export.

wsData, as an example assume row 1 is the header row.
wsFilter would be only 2 columns (with headers corresponding to A and AG), corresponding to Column A and AG.
On wsReport, you only have to clear contents and enter the column headers from wsData that you would want to appear on the customized report.

You will need 3 ranges, 1 for each worksheet. i.e., rngData, rngFilter, rngReport

The code to creating the report is easy as:

```
rngData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngFilter, rngReport
```

(I won't get into how to decide on the ranges as the video does it better than I would be able to).

Then next step should be: How to enter the filter criteria?

Comment: Thank you so much, so the 200-400 would be things like G-#### it's a way of identifying customers, then I would have set 5 phrases to generate differently formatted templates and such, so I wasn't sure if I could do it without the filter option, but that would make it miles easier. is the rngdata variable what I would use on my master or would I use rangedata for the other sheet which has the G-####?

Comment: Please see Edit 1